# Build a tree from a flat array

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree, nodes

I was faced with the question of building a tree from a flat array. We have an array.

```json
[
    {
        "h1": "h001",
        "h2": "z001"
    },
    {
        "h1": "h002",
        "h2": "z002"
    },
    {
        "h1": "h003",
        "h2": "z003"
    }
]
```

I would like to get something like this:

```json
[{
    "h1": "h001",
    "h2": "z001",
    "children": {
        "h1": "h002",
        "h2": "z002",
        "children": {
            "h1": "h003",
            "h2": "z003"
        }
    }
}]
```

Is there a way to implement this?

Thanks!

Comment: How the data is related ? how Child node and Parent node is connected ?

Comment: Is child node connected via index ? like `node[1]` is connected `node[0]`...Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. the children need to be connected via the index. Only how to implement this moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a great place to use the array `map()` method. Essentially, we'll takin a shallow copy of the array using `slice()`, then `reverse()` it, then make each object a property of the previous object's under the `children` property. When we are done, we re-`reverse()` the array to get the original order and take the first item.

```js
let values = [{
    "h1": "h001",
    "h2": "z001"
}, {
    "h1": "h002",
    "h2": "z002"
}, {
    "h1": "h003",
    "h2": "z003"
}];

let newValues = values.slice().reverse().map((e,i,a) => i ? (a[i] = { ...e, children: a[i-1] }) : a[i]).reverse()[0];

console.log(newValues);
```

This outputs:

```json
{
  "h1": "h001",
  "h2": "z001",
  "children": {
    "h1": "h002",
    "h2": "z002",
    "children": {
      "h1": "h003",
      "h2": "z003"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @РегиональныйцентрОрион This solution allows you to get the result you're looking for inline, without needing to use a function, and without recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate by there index and add next node to the previous index.

Implementation:

```js
const nodes = [{ "h1": "h001", "h2": "z001" }, { "h1": "h002", "h2": "z002" }, { "h1": "h003", "h2": "z003" }];

for (let i = 1; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    nodes[i - 1].children = nodes[i];
}

console.log('solutionByIndex', nodes[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion:

```js
function to_tree(vals){
   var v = vals.shift()
   return vals.length ? {...v, children:to_tree(vals)} : v
}
var vals = [{ "h1": "h001", "h2": "z001" }, { "h1": "h002", "h2": "z002" }, { "h1": "h003", "h2": "z003" }];
console.log([to_tree(vals)])
```